# Best way to ensure Item can only be used by 1 user

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, api

I have a web application with two main table (All tasks) and (In progress). When you open a task from (All tasks) the item gets moved into (In progress). Now if users on different pc's open the task at the same time it will duplicate.

In your guys opinions what is the best way to make sure duplicates don't happen.

I currently have a column thats 0 if not processed and 1 if processed but this still gives a 2-3 second period where the task can be opened from two pcs at the same time.

I have looked into guid's and using sql transactions although ive read this slows things down abit

I hope this makes sense my dudes

Thanks in advance

a junior devi

Comment: Duplicates happen when you save a new record in the database. Make sure that you don't save a record when it is not required.

Comment: You should check if row already existing or not and based on that perform the operation or discard it.

Comment: Use transactions, they shouldn't slow things down if you use them correctly.  The second user will wait for 2-3 seconds while the transaction from the first user completes, and this should be the only slow down.  You could also add an "in progress" flag, set this to 1 in a transaction if it's 0, then set it back to 0 when processing completes, also in a transaction.  Now the second user will only be delayed a split second then will see the "in progress" flag has been set and fail to get the task?

Comment: @RichardHansell So I currently am using a in progress flag but it allows that 2 second gap where two people can open the same task. I shall try the transactions and see how it effects performance. thanks man :)

Comment: Sorry guys I didnt clarify enough. Once the same task manages to get opened by two pc's at the same time all data entered on that task will be duplicated in the db not necessarily the task itself. So I need an efficient flag of sorts.

Comment: @RichardHansell is right.  Transactions are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't meant to be a solution, just a quick framework to get you started:

```
CREATE TABLE #tasks (task_id INT, other_stuff VARCHAR(50), held BIT);
INSERT INTO #tasks SELECT 1, 'My Test Task', 0;
CREATE TABLE #work_queue (task_id INT);

--User #1 puts a task onto the work queue
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE #tasks SET held = 1 WHERE task_id = 1 AND held = 0;
    --Did we get it?
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1
        INSERT INTO #work_queue SELECT 1;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;

--User #2 fails to get a handle to the task so nothing is put onto the work queue
--Note that this can be run asynch from a second session
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE #tasks SET held = 1 WHERE task_id = 1 AND held = 0;
    --Did we get it?
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1
        INSERT INTO #work_queue SELECT 1;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;

--Task completes
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    DELETE FROM #work_queue WHERE task_id = 1;
    UPDATE #tasks SET held = 0 WHERE task_id = 1;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

If a user comes along to "book out" a task then one of these results will occur:

- they get a "lock" by setting the held flag to 1 where it was previously zero.  So the task is booked out and added to the in progress table (work queue in my example);
- they can't book out the task, as it's already been booked out by someone else.  So nothing happens.

If you were to run the "book out stage" from multiple users simultaneously then only one user would get the task, but there would be little in the way of "slow down".

---

Another (better?) way of handling this would be to store the user_id of the user who has a job running instead of a BIT flag.  Now you know who has the job rather than simply knowing that someone has it "booked out" so you can't get it?

Answer (score 0):

Give the destination table a column that will contain the primary key from the source table, and put a uniqueness constraint on it. Or, if possible, simply give them the same primary key.

For example, if your `AllTasks` table has a primary key of `TaskID`, put a `TaskID` column in your `InProgress` table too, and put a uniqueness constraint on it. If two users try to copy the same record, the second record will violate the constraint and the insert will fail.